# how to count opened newwindows?

Tags: javascript, jsf

I want to count the number of opened new windows.

But, when i close the opened newWindow ,then reduce the window count.

My new window have ***closelink*** also.

May be i choose either ***closelink*** or ***browser close window***.

**Update**

If i have open 2 new window, then i calculate currently opened window.

But, if any window i close using ( close link, or browser closewindow),  now only one new window is opened.

Here i don't know, how to show the opened window count is 1.

Totally 4 files are : **MainPage.jsp** , **newwindow1.jsp** , **newwindow2.jsp** and **windowcount.js**

**MainPage.jsp**

```
<f:view>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">            
        <a4j:loadScript src = "windowcount.js" />
    </head>
    <body>                     
            <h:outputLink value="#" onclick="window.open('newwindow1.jsp','firstwindow','width=600,height=600');addWindowCount();">
                <h:outputText value="new Window1"/>
            </h:outputLink>

            <h:outputLink value="#" onclick="window.open('newwindow2.jsp','secondWindow','width=600,height=600');addWindowCount();">
                <h:outputText value="New window 2"/>
            </h:outputLink>                

        <a4j:commandButton value="Get Window Count" onclick="getNewWindowCount();"/> 

    </body>
</html>
```

**newwindow1.jsp**

```
<f:view>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">           
        <title>First Window</title>           
    </head>
    <body>          
         <a4j:commandLink id="firstWindowCloseLinkId" 
                          value="Close Window" 
                          onclick="javascript:window.close()"/>            
    </body>
</html>
```

**newwindow2.jsp**

```
<f:view>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">           
        <title>Second Window</title>           
    </head>
    <body>          
         <a4j:commandLink id="secondWindowCloseLinkId" 
                          value="Close Window" 
                          onclick="javascript:window.close()"/>            
    </body>
</html>
```

**windowcount.js**

```
var countNewWindow = 0;

function addWindowCount()
{
     countNewWindow++;
}

function getNewWindowCount()
{
    alert("Current opened NewWindow : " + countNewWindow);
}
```

Help me about this.
Thanks for your effort.

Comment: Are these new windows being opened by your code using window.open() ?

Comment: yes. opened new window using window.open() method.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

JavaScript doesn't have access to other open windows, unless they were opened using `window.open()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just i add one more button and javscript. But i can't get the openedPopup window count.
**MainPage.jsp**

```
<a4j:commandButton value="PopupCount" onclick="countOpenPopups();"/>
```

And javaScript is :

```
function countOpenPopups()
{    
   var iCount = 0;
   for (var i = 0; i < eWebEditPro.popups.length; i++)
   {
       if (eWebEditPro.popups[i].isOpen())
       {
          iCount++;
       }
   }
   alert("iCount : " +iCount);
```

}

I refer this. 
http://dev.ektron.com/kb_article.aspx?id=568

I think this script related to **eWebEditPro**.
Is possible to implement to normal browser link(FireFox,IE etc...)